# Letter Sequence Shape Shifter

Tags: letter-sequence

IIIIIIIIIIIIII
TTTTTT
LLLLLLL
UUUUU
JJJJJJJ

What's the next logical sequence?

Comment: What are the previous sequences? Are they horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @Deusovi They are horizontal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> SSSSSS

because

> Each new line just seems to add, move, or remove a line/curve to create a new letter, and it seems like the most likely next letter would be going from J to S, as moving or removing a line would either not result in a letter or would be a letter already used, and to go from J to S, you just add a right facing curve at the top.

This is a bit of a stretch, I know, but it seems to fit the title, so I thought I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry if that it is not the intendend solution but I've been trapped with this once :

the next sequence might be :

> I
> T
> L
> U
> J

Comment: Way too easy. The correct sequence is horizontal.

Comment: Easy = simplest = correct!

Answer (score 6):

This is not really an answer but this might be the direction the OP is looking for.

Say each line out loud like
IIIIIIIII = Is = ice
TTTTTT = Ts = teas
LLLLLLL = Ls = Els
UUUUU = Us = Yous
JJJJJJJ = Js = Jays

So we need to finish a phrase that goes something like "Ice tea sells you sjay..." but I can't find a solution.

Comment: That's creative.

Answer (score 4):

IIIIIIIIIIIIII
TTTTTT
LLLLLLL
UUUUU
JJJJJJJ

Each of these rows are

> basically a vertical line with a different configuration of "extra stuff". The first row has the "extra stuff" as a disjoint second vertical line (noticing there are roughly twice as many characters in the first row as any other row).

The next row could be

> CCCCCCC

Comment: I like your explanation, but where's the vertical line in C?

Comment: On the left side. Imagine it written on a 7-segment display.

Comment: I wrote the riddle in SE display font.

Answer (score 2):

The next sequence is

> TTTTTT

because

> The letters start as 'I' then become 'T' (I am not sure why) after that 'L' which could be seen as the beginning of a Turn counter clockwise, then comes 'U' which is mid turn and then 'J' which is the end of the turn. Next would be 'T' since it lapsed back again.

Bonus:

> Given that logic the sequence after that should be 'I' again

I highly doubt this is the correct answer (since I am still missing something), but I'll still try since I am really interested in the correct solution

Comment: Not correct, but I think you're onto something.

Comment: @LN6595 some kind of hint or additional information would be nice. I will try to come up with a concept that can explain the "Ts"

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines, but there's no indication that the series ever repeats.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is BBBBBBBBBBBBBB because I appeared 14 times and the sequence was 11, 8, 9 , then 11 again thats why B was used

Comment: Where did you get B? Also, there are five given lines.